# highlighting C/C++ functions in notepad++

Tags: c, function, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I love Notepad++ but cannot find a way to highight C/C++ **functions**. jEdit does it easily.
Is there a way to do it in Notepad++?

Comment: i would suggest a better editor for your work <strong>there are MANY, its a matter of personal taste</strong> that said, my personall perference goes to gedit, light, highlighting, snipetts ...

Comment: As I said jEdit also does that but I love the versatility of Notepad++.

Comment: on notepad++, -->language-->C and that should highlight your code

Comment: Yes, but it does not highlight functions in C/C++.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files#U

instructions on bottom

Comment: @TJ1 if you cant find any syntax highlighting scheme for C/C++, consider neither notepad++ has built-in nor anyone has made one

Comment: I also love Notepad++, but I wouldn't consider it as my primary editor for C++.

Comment: There is syntax highlighting for C/C++ in Notepad++, it hightlights a lot of things, but not **functions**.

Comment: What do you use for that? I just want to look at the codes, I don't want to compile or anything.

Comment: For just looking, I would also use it. I thought you are actually developing something, for this I use Eclipse or Visual Studio. I can see that a lightweight editor might have it'smerrits though.